# Issue with the format in anytime package

Tags: r, date, anytime

```
library("anytime")
```

This works well:

```
anytime("08/24/2014 01:28:00")
anytime("2014/08/24 01:28:00")

[1] "2014-08-24 00:28:00 NZST"
```

This doesn't:

```
anytime("24/08/2014 01:28:00")
anytime("2014/24/08 01:28:00")

[1] NA
```

What is the reason for this and what would be the options (using anytime package ONLY)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add the formats with `addFormats` in `anytime` if that formats are not in the default list of formats by using

```
getFormats()
#[1] "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f"    "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S%f"    "%Y%m%d %H%M%S%f"       
#[4] "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S%f"      "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%f"    "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S%f"   
#[7] "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S%f"    "%Y/%b/%d %H:%M:%S%f"    "%Y%b%d %H%M%S%F"       
#[10] "%Y%b%d %H:%M:%S%F"      "%b/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%f"    "%b-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S%f"   
#[13] "%d.%b.%Y %H:%M:%S%f"    "%Y-%B-%d %H:%M:%S%f"    "%Y/%B/%d %H:%M:%S%f"   
#[16] "%Y%B%d %H%M%S%f"        "%Y%B%d %H:%M:%S%f"      "%B/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%f"   
#[19] "%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S%f"    "%d.%B.%Y %H:%M:%S%f"    "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S%F %Y"
#[22] "%Y-%m-%d"               "%Y%m%d"                 "%m/%d/%Y"              
#[25] "%m-%d-%Y"               "%Y-%b-%d"               "%Y%b%d"                
#[28] "%b/%d/%Y"               "%b-%d-%Y"               "%Y-%B-%d"              
#[31] "%Y%B%d"                 "%B/%d/%Y"               "%B-%d-%Y"
```

If we check the `format` that gives NA, it is not in the `getFormats` list

```
c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S") %in% getFormats()
#[1] FALSE FALSE
```

So, we can add the formats with `addFormats` and apply the `anytime`

```
anytime::addFormats(c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S")) 
anytime("24/08/2014 01:28:00")
#[1] "2014-08-24 01:28:00 IST"
anytime("2014/24/08 01:28:00")
#[1] "2014-08-24 01:28:00 IST"
```

#### Update

In the latest version of `anytime`, there are 41 formats in `getFormats()`

```
length(getFormats())
#[1] 41
```

But, the format specified in the OP's post is still not included and would have to follow the `addFormats` route

Comment: Thanks. If multiple formats can be simultaneously defined, what happens when the argument is ambiguous? Say
anytime("03/01/2014 01:28:00")

Comment: @ed_sans this is already in the formats i.e. `anytime("03/01/2014 01:28:00")
#[1] "2014-03-01 01:28:00 IST"`  I think it is very difficult for the machine to process if it is ambiguous without specifying the format.  You will have the same problem when you are using `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`.  Only option is to make sure that you as an user knows exactly whether it is month followed by day or day followed by month to correctly insert the format.

Comment: What I mean is how the function decides what format to use when matching several e.g. "03/01/2014" =  1st of March or 3th of January?

Comment: @ed_sans  I updated my earlier comment.  Based on the list of `getFormats`, it is only having `%m` followed by %d` as default.  So it will read as March 01

Comment: @SymbolixAU  Thanks, I have `anytime_0.0.2`